# How to get latest version in TFS of Specific Project

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk, tfvc

I'm working on CheckingIn Items through C# code,where I have `workspace.Get();`
Where it is getting all the projects in the Collection.
I would like to get latest version of only a particular project.Canyone anyone help me to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the overload of `workspace.Get` that accepts a `GetRequest` object. Set the `Itemspec` property of the `GetRequest` to `$/Project Name` to scope the get action to a specific team project.

See also:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139312.aspx